pandas series get value by index with fill value if the index does not exist
ts = pd.Series({'a' : 1, 'b' : 2})
ids = ['a','c'] # 'c' is not in the index

# the result I want
np.array([ts.get(k, np.nan) for k in ids])

Is there a pandas native way to achieve this?

reindex and access the underlying numpy array:
out = ts.reindex(ids).values

# or
# out = ts.reindex(ids).to_numpy()

Output: array([ 1., nan])
Note that the fill_value in reindex is NaN by default, you can change it if desired:
ts.reindex(ids, fill_value=0).values
# array([1, 0])


You can convert the list to Series then map the original Series
out = pd.Series(ids).map(ts).tolist()

print(out)

[1.0, nan]

Or you can filled the missing value in original Series index with reindex
out = ts.reindex(ids).tolist()

